# Is there a function to remove/suppress audio echoing using Agora web sdk ng?

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

In live video streaming the audio gets echoed when there are two or more speakers joined the stream. Is there any function in Agora web SDK I could use to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do try the self check methods at https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/echo.
2. Try `audioTrack.stop()` if it still persists (try to avoid playing that microphone track in the first place).
3. If the issue persists, contact Agora customer support (support@agora.io) and submit the issue with the following information:

- The name of the channel where the echo occurs.
- The uids of the users who hear the echo.
- The uid of the user who causes the echo.
- The recording files, if available.

Comment: When I should have to use audioTrack.stop() method?

Comment: audioTrack.stop() should be used on localAudioTrack() object?

Comment: @VishwanathA did you get this issue resolved? If so, how?

I'm currently experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Yes for this you can use the AEC and ANS properties of the agora. With these, you can suppress the echo.

```
await AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAudioTrack({
        AEC: true, ANS: true
      });
```

Comment: Should I assign it to `rtc.localAudioTrack`?

Comment: Yes, sure you can do that.